# Where are Edge browser 'Other Search Engines' settings stored?

Tags: settings, microsoft-edge

Where are Edge browser 'Other Search Engines' settings stored?

If it stored as a file, then I want to copy/paste to another profile.

Comment: Hi @Jang-won Seo. May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in `Web Data` file under your profile folder. You can find your profile path in `edge://version/`.